# Changing RestKit version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, restkit

I was developing an iOS app with RestKit 0.10, but now I must upgrade to version 0.20, that has different methods to do the calls.

I've removed the old library and I've tried to add the new one, but XCode still detecting somehow the first headers version, and when I compile it throws errors when it tries to link and don't find the methods.

I've tried to clean the project, closing and opening XCode, but the error persists.

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting derived data.

```
Organizer -> Project -> Derived Data / Delete.
```

Also check the Header search paths in your Target's build settings.